# Fetching block template from node

Tags: parity, json-rpc, blocks, protocol, block-header

The most famous opensource pool uses [eth_getBlockByNumber](https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool/blob/master/rpc/rpc.go#L102) method with parameter *"pending"* to get block template and generate jobs from it. But now, in parity, I found that this parameter is [deprecated](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/blob/master/rpc/src/v1/impls/eth.rs#L218) and I would like to understand why. Also, if this is really bad way to get a block template from the node, I would like to know how to do it right? Perhaps I need to use another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an rpc call that is implemented across clients and I doubt Parity has any plans to deprecate this, as it would break too many application.

There is however a strong desire to stop support for account management and hence most of the rpcs to do with account management have a deprecation notice.

You can view them here: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/search?q=self.deprecation_notice.print&unscoped_q=self.deprecation_notice.print